# Any plans for enabling HTTP/2?

Tags: feature-request

Will Stack Overflow enable HTTP/2? If not soon, why?

Comment: I imagine that a precursor to this would be SSL globally throughout, since most modern evergreen browsers only support [HTTP2 through TLS](http://caniuse.com/#feat=http2).

Comment: Seems unlikely, currently no browser supports HTTP/2 unencrypted and stackoverflow does not support https which would presumably be a prerequisite first step.

Comment: https is [status-planned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116782/better-https-support-for-stack-exchange-sites) since 2011... so we are about to enter the 6 to 8 years timeframe ...

Comment: @rene I'm so excited!!

Answer (score 3):

> Any plans for enabling HTTP/2?

Any plans to enabling http2 are precluded by TLS global support, since browsers only support http2 through TLS connections, and The Plan™ for TLS has taken 6 to 8 big units of time already. So, to answer your question, we don't know yet, since TLS hasn't been enabled.